# Position at the top and bottom of two seperate divs

Tags: html, css

I want to fade out the top and bottom of two separate divs.

Right now I'm trying to use position:absolute and top:1px on the top one and bottom: 1px on the bottom one. Was not working for me, uses the parent div? Which was causing them to show up in the wrong places.

This fiddle shows where I am:

http://jsfiddle.net/mstefanko/23mfk/

What I want is for the top and bottom of each div to have the fade demonstrated in the fiddle.

Comment: Could you try to re-explain what you are looking for? It's a little hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.inner-1` and `.inner-2` both have absolutely positioned elements within them. These elements are being positioned in relation to the viewport, and not their parent. You'll need to set `.inner-1` and `.inner-2` to a relative position:

```
.inner-1,
.inner-2 {
  position: relative;
}
```

This will cause the gradient elements to appear at the top and bottom of these containers.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/23mfk/1/